# Sync between Doctrine2 and FOSElasticaBundle is not realtime?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have url `/posts` to list latest 10 **active** posts. When I edit the last post (1st of those 10), the change seem not sync to elasticsearch at realtime.

Here is my code:

```
    $post = $this->findPostBy....;

    /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post->setStatus(PostModel::STATUS_DELETED);
    $entityManager->persist($post);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirect('/posts');
```

After above code is executed, I will be redirected to `/posts` but the last post which has just been edited and has its status changed to **deleted** still get listed as latest 10 **active** posts (which is definitely wrong). It only disappears when I refresh the page (`/posts`).

Code for `/posts`:

```
    /** @var TransformedFinder $finder */
    $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.index_name.post');
    $query = new Query();
    $filter = new Term(array('status' => PostModel::STATUS_ACTIVE));
    $query->setFilter($filter);
    $query->addSort(array('tttAt' => array('order' => 'desc')));
    $posts = $finder->find($query);
```

My mapping:

```
        types:
            post:
                mappings:
                    title:
                        type: string
                        analyzer: post_analyzer
                    description:
                        type: string
                        analyzer: post_analyzer
                    status:
                        type: integer
                    tttAt :
                        type : date
                    createdAt :
                        type : date
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: MyBundle\Entity\Post
                    finder: ~
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
```

Can someone explain me why and how to solve that problem?

**Updated:** If I use xdebug to delay the redirection in about 1 or 2 seconds, the post will not be listed in `/posts` any more. So I guest that there was not enough time for ElasticSearch to re-index. Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: You may find some hints by reading [docs about flushing method](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/types.md#flushing-method). I am not certain if it will solve your issue, but still worth to read.

Comment: Is it because ElastisSearch does not synchronously index documents, and so you are facing a race condition? Calling refresh on the index forces it to reindex which would explain why it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution, maybe not the best way but at least it works:

```
    /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post->setStatus(PostModel::STATUS_DELETED);
    $entityManager->persist($post);
    $entityManager->flush();

    /** @var Index $type */
    $type = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.index.index_name');
    $type->refresh();
```

Refreshing index before redirection will do the strick :)

Comment: Forcing ElasticSearch refresh is not really good, it occurs naturally every 1 second. But forcing the refresh in your code for each user will cause more problems & performance issues especially as your user base increase / page hits. I would look into another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by Michael Bui, I found the following snippet to do the trick for me with the latest versions of FOSElasticaBundle:

```
/** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$post->setStatus(PostModel::STATUS_DELETED);
$entityManager->persist($post);
$entityManager->flush();

/** @var \Elastica\Type $type */
$type = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.index.--INDEX--.--TYPE--');
$type->getIndex()->refresh();
```

The comments posted for his answer obviously still apply: Don't use this for anything that is being done often.

Another, simple, solution would be to just sleep for whatever your refresh interval is in ElasticSearch, by default set to one second.